# Programatic addition of controls disappears when I change orientation in iOS

Tags: ios

I am adding controls (subviews) to a view programatically in iOS7/xCode project. When I flip orientations, the controls added disappear. Why? How to ensure that the controls reappear when I flip orientations? What goes behind the scenes when I flip orientation?

Comment: Are the frames changing so that the views go off the side of the screen?

Comment: share some code then only can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

By default, frames do not update themselves on orientation change events. Either you:

1. Manually update the frames
2. Use NSLayoutConstraint, which is the new, preferred way: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/

Note that you can assign constraints visually in Interface Builder. New in XCode 5 is that constraints have to be added manually and are no longer required, like in version 4.